# make an object out of an array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am trying to search one word in my whole table.
So if you search Eminem, you have to get everything with the word Eminem.

I search

```
<?php

 $sql="SELECT * FROM album WHERE albumartiest like '$zoek'";
    $resultaatcolumn = Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->queryAll();                         
    if($resultaatcolumn != null){
     $zoekresultaat[] = $resultaatcolumn;}
 $sql="select * from album where albumnaam like '%$zoek%'";
    $resultaatcolumn = Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    if($resultaatcolumn != null){
     $zoekresultaat[] = $resultaatcolumn;}
 $sql="select * from album where albumartiest like '%$zoek%'";
    $resultaatcolumn = Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    if($resultaatcolumn != null){
     $zoekresultaat[] = $resultaatcolumn;}
 $sql="select * from album where albumgenre like '%$zoek%'";
    $resultaatcolumn = Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    if($resultaatcolumn != null){
     $zoekresultaat[] = $resultaatcolumn;}
 $sql="select * from album where albumafspeelijst like '%$zoek%'";
    $resultaatcolumn = Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    if($resultaatcolumn != null){
     $zoekresultaat[] = $resultaatcolumn;}
```

It works, but not exactly how I want it.
The result is this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [albumcode] => 45 [albumnaam] => recovery [albumafspeelijst] => ["Cold Wind Blows","Talkin' 2 Myself","On Fire","Won't Back Down","W.T.P.","Going Through Changes","Not Afraid","Seduction","No Love","Space Bound","Cinderella Man","To Life","So Bad","Almost Famous","Love The Way You Lie","You're Never Over",""] [albumartiest] => Eminem [albumgenre] => hip-hop [albumimage] => images\eminemrecovery.png [albumprijs] => 20 ) ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [albumcode] => 45 [albumnaam] => recovery [albumafspeelijst] => ["Cold Wind Blows","Talkin' 2 Myself","On Fire","Won't Back Down","W.T.P.","Going Through Changes","Not Afraid","Seduction","No Love","Space Bound","Cinderella Man","To Life","So Bad","Almost Famous","Love The Way You Lie","You're Never Over",""] [albumartiest] => Eminem [albumgenre] => hip-hop [albumimage] => images\eminemrecovery.png [albumprijs] => 20 ) ) )
```

that's okay, but what I want is take out variable's and use it.

is there a way that I can get variable's out of the array and use it?
If you guys want more information about my code please ask!

Comment: Do you want to access the result like an object or?

Comment: yes, if that helps me to get the variables out of the array

Comment: Do you have a model for the table  `album`?

Comment: You may try like, `(object)$zoekresultaat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
Yii::app()->db->CreateCommand($sql)->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->queryAll()
```

This will give you an array of objects with **column name as the properties**.

Eg:-

```
foreach($result as $row)
{
echo $row->albumcode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the result set like an object you can use the native PHP class `ArrayObject` and provide the flag to indicate that.

```
$album = new ArrayObject($result, ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);
```

You can now access the results like the following:

```
$code = $album->albumcode;
$name = $album->albumnaam;
```

Hope this can guide you, happy coding!

Comment: thanks for your reply, But if I do this, I get an error that says undefined index

Comment: I do not understand why you get an error. Please make sure the variable name is spelled according to your database columns. If they are, I am clueless, sorry.

Comment: Arrays can have indexes like $array["My Name"] and $array[3],, object fields follow specific naming conventions. For example $my_object->3 is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

uhhh just do

```
foreach($zoekresultaat as $key => $value) {
   //do what I want with each seperate returened result. The array key is in $key and the result array is in $value
   echo $value['albumcode'] . ' = '. $value['albumnaam'];
```

}

aka, basic php

And please for the security of your app, learn how to do prepared statements in yii

The way your query is now I could wipe your entire database

Comment: Yes thanks, but it is for school so I would never put it online or something. If I use your solution my localhost crashes.

Comment: Ugh, even I am not excempt from errors :P try the modified code ;-)